# facilitate reading

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "reading" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> We thank the reviewer for the comment here, the comment is noted and
>   the manuscript has been completely revised accordingly. We have used
>   colored ink to facilitate **reading**.

Comment: The word "reading" is fine. I would use "for easier reading" rather than "to facilitate reading" – it's simply easier reading.

Answer (score 0):

It would be understood, but it sounds a little awkward as written.  "Facilitate" can mean 'make easier', but in this context I'd read it as 'make possible'.  Because any ink makes reading possible, it doesn't make perfect sense.  Like J.R. says in the comments, I'd write this as:

> We have used colored ink for ease of reading.

Or if you want to use the word 'facilitate', I'd maybe write

> We have used colored ink to facilitate easy reading.

But I'd prefer the first sentence.

Comment: maybe "for **the** ease of reading"? I also do not really agree with "facilitate easy reading" - "facilitate" itself implies "making easy"